# Angular reactive form, removed elements still validate

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a set of inputs that are displayed for the user or not depending on selected options. If the user selects an option that shows an input, changes their option that removes it, then submits the removed input causes the validation to fail. However, if they never select the option to show said input the validation is fine.

For example:

Filling out a form if they select "currently employed" an input asking for the name of the employer displays. If they deselect that option the name field is gone but invalidates the form. If they never select it at all, validation is fine.

Comment: please add some codes

Comment: @RezaRahmati it's comprised of 100's of lines of code across multiple components.

Comment: Just create minimum code with the reproducible issue and share, you can use stackblitz

Comment: @RezaRahmati this is a dynamically built form that add/removes inputs based on selections from the user, popping in code isn't that straight forward.

Comment: @RezaRahmati It would take me the better part of a day to try to recreate this. The question is, can I tell angular reactive forms to no validate something that is no longer on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is really hard to solve without any more information.

But I think your problem is that the [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) state does still have [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) attached to the [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl).

When removing a `FormControl` you also need to clear the validators attached to the `FormGroup`.

```js
this.formGroup.get('formControl').clearValidators();
this.formGroup.get('formControl').updateValueAndValidity();
```

You also have the possibility to remove or add the entire formControl from the `FormGroup`.

```
addControl(name: string, control: AbstractControl): void
removeControl(name: string): void
```

More information [about Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) can be read at the angular.io site.